# Sort a linked list changing pointer's values

Tags: c, list, sorting, pointers

Im trying to make a code to sort a linked list changin the pointers value.The program crashes when i get to the last node.The searchMinor functions works fine, the problem is in the logic of sortList.

```
typedef struct{
    int num;
}t_dataL;

typedef struct s_nodeL{
    t_dataL dataL;
    struct s_nodeL *next;
}t_nodeL;

typedef t_nodeL *t_list;

t_list *searchMinor(t_nodeL*n){
    t_list *min=&n, *l=&n;
    l=&(*l)->next;
    while(*l) {
        if( (*l)->dataL.num < (*min)->dataL.num )min=l;
        l=&(*l)->next;
    }
    return min;
}

void sortList(t_list *l){
    t_nodeL *nbegin=*l;           //save the beginig of the list in nbegin
    t_list *plec,*aux;
    plec=searchMinor(nbegin);    //search the minor from the begining
    *l=*plec;                  //put as the first elemnet on the list the fisrt minor value
    while(nbegin->next){
        aux=&(*plec)->next;    //Save the value of the next of the minor in aux
        *plec=*aux;          //remove the minor from the list
        plec=searchMinor(nbegin); //search the new minor from the begining of the list
        *aux=*plec;         //the next of the old minor is the new minor
    }
}
```

Comment: Your coding style is terrible, did you know the compiler ignores whitespaces? Humans don't. Which is why we don't write: *Yourcodingstyleisterrible,didyouknowthecompilerignoreswhitespaces?*

Comment: `t_list *min=&n, *l=&n;` : `&n` is local pointer address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obtaining the local copy of `nbegin` in `sortList`. Because you are returning local copy, it is the reason of *undefined behaviour*. Instead, you have to pass the address of it. Like,

```
// edit the function according to the signature
t_list *searchMinor(t_nodeL **n); 

// and call like in sortList
searchMinor(&nbegin)
```